# Shuffle method doesn't work swap values?

Tags: java, inheritance

let's i have a class named **Card.java**:

```
public class Card{
    private int face, suit;
    ...
    public void setFace(int newFace){
        face = newFace;
    }
    public void setSuit(int newSuit){
        suit = newSuit;
    }
}
```

and **DeckOfCards.java**

```
public class DeckOfCards extends Card{
    public Card[] newDeck = new Card[52];
    public void Shuffle(){


    }
    main(){
        DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards();
        deck.Shuffle();
    }
}
```

**shuffle**

```
   public void Shuffle(){                                    //Shuffles 52 times
      Random ran = new Random();
      int tmp_face, tmp_suit;
      int card1_idx;
      int card2_idx;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         card1_idx = ran.nextInt(52);
         card2_idx = ran.nextInt(52);
         tmp_face = newDeck[card1_idx].getFace();
         tmp_suit = newDeck[card1_idx].getSuit();
         System.out.println(" Inx1 is " + newDeck[card1_idx].getFace());
         System.out.println(" Ind2 is " + newDeck[card2_idx].getFace());
         newDeck[card1_idx].setFace(newDeck[card2_idx].getFace());
         newDeck[card1_idx].setSuit(newDeck[card2_idx].getSuit());
         newDeck[card2_idx].setFace(tmp_face);
         newDeck[card2_idx].setSuit(tmp_suit);
         System.out.println(" Swapped Ind1 is " + newDeck[card1_idx].getFace());
         System.out.println(" Swapped Ind2 is " + newDeck[card2_idx].getFace());
      }
   }
```

After I all deck.Shuffle(), I noticed the deck is shuffled as I print them all, they are still in the same order before shuffle. Would this have to do with inheritance? Can the childclass method modify its member data that is the data type of parent class?

Comment: Show us the implementation of `Shuffle()`.

Comment: without seeing the code of Shuffle (which should be shuffle following naming conventions), you don't return the result from shuffle, so how do you expect to have it afterwards?

Comment: how did you shuffle the cards ??

Comment: For one thing, why does DeckOfCards extend card? Should DeckOfCards have the method setSuit()? Can you set the suit of a deck? If not, Deck should not extend Card. DeckOfCards should probably be its own class that does not extend anything.

Comment: What you want to use here is [composition, not inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). A deck of cards isn't a type of card. A deck of cards *contains* cards.

Comment: Side note: consider changing your design. Do you think that a real card in real life can change its face or suit? No, it can't; and so should you model your objects as well. Meaning: make your fields final; and assign them using a constructor. This will also allow you to create equals/hashcode methods that simply "do the right" thing (for example allowing you to easily compare two cards).

Comment: Maybe you're calling `deck.Shuffle()` and then checking `this.newDeck`. You need to check `deck.newDeck`. My best guess.

Comment: Your way of shuffling is bizarre anyway. Shuffling a deck, in real life, consists in moving the cards in the deck randomly. Your method doesn't do that: its leaves all the cards in the same position, but "reprints" them: the queen of hearts becomes the 2 of diamonds, etc. Just use `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(newDeck))`.